# using mysqli driver in ci

Tags: codeigniter

I am using codeigniter version 3.0.5 and i want to use mysqli instead of mysql.
For this i have changed  `$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql'` to `$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli'` and `var $dbdriver = 'mysql'` to `var $dbdriver = 'mysqli'` in  system/database/DB_driver.php. Now my code from model,controller and view are like this:

My controller:

```
public function home()
{   
    $this->load->model('Destination_model');
    $data['main_content']="home_view";
    $data['values']=$this->Destination_model->getAllLocation();
    $this->load->view('include/template',$data);
}
```

my model :

```
public function getAllLocation()
{
    $query=$this->db->get('tbl_location');
    
    if($query->num_rows > 0)
        {
    return $query->result();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and now my View:

```
<h3 class="search-head">Select list (select one)</h3></label>
 <?php
        $extra='class="form-control border-radius"';
        echo form_error('source');
                            
        $place=array();
        $place[]="Select";
    foreach($values as $val){
            $place[$val->place_id]=$val->place_name;
    }
                                                                    
    echo form_dropdown('source', $place, set_value('source'),$extra);
?>
```

I have tried to access values from model to load in combo but it displays error

> Severity: Warning
> Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
> Filename: views/home_view.php
> Line Number: 18

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot run foreach on an object, instead of using `$query->result()` try using `$query->result_array()`

Model:

```
public function getAllLocation()
{
    $query=$this->db->get('tbl_location');

    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
    return $query->result_array();
    }
    return [];
}
```

View:

```
<h3 class="search-head">Select list (select one)</h3></label>
 <?php
        $extra='class="form-control border-radius"';
        echo form_error('source');

        $place=array();
        $place[]="Select";
    foreach($values as $val){
            $place[$val['place_id']]=$val['place_name'];
    }

    echo form_dropdown('source', $place, set_value('source'),$extra);
?>
```

Comment: can you show the code .i tried as you said still same problem

Comment: Error is gone but data not loading in combo

Comment: My bad, please update your code change `$query->num_rows` to `$query->num_rows()`

Answer (score 3):

In your model use $query->num_rows() in place of $query->num_rows and in your view file always check for the array before foreach loop

```
if(is_array($values) && count($values)>0){
    foreach($values as $val){
            $place[$val->place_id]=$val->place_name;
    }
}
```